# Apache Pulsar Java client taking too much memory (OOM)

Tags: apache-pulsar

I wrote a simple Apache Pulsar client with Spring boot - a pulsar-producer initialized as beans that will be used in the rest controller to publish incoming api messages to Pulsar, and a consumer that consumes message, prints some values in console & acknowledge.

As of now the application is very simple, but the moment this spring-boot app loads I see memory peak, at times getting OOM. Is there any specific configuration to be used when using Pulsar client with Spring-boot?

The code is mostly the one found the Pulsar doc.

Comment: Enjoy or inspire from my Pulsar Library for Spring Boot in your next project: https://github.com/majusko/pulsar-java-spring-boot-starter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering this to doc this issue - **do not** use the loops to consume messages, instead adopt the `MessageListener` subscribed to consumer via

`consumer.messageListener(new Myconsumer())`

or

`consumer.messageListener((consumer, msg)->{//do something})`

Docs didnt mention this, but I found surfing the consumer api.